# How to convert $z=\sin(x)\sin(y)$ to a parametric equation?

Tags: trigonometry, parametric

I want to convert $z=\sin(2\pi x)\sin(2\pi y)$ to a parametric equation such as $x=f(t)$, $y=g(t)$, $z=k(t)$.

Comment: You can't do that since $x$ and $y$ are independent, they can't both be determined by a single variable.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: As, $z=\sin(2\pi x)\sin(2\pi y)$ contains three free variable in a single equation, that means we should need atleast two independent variables to connect those variables through the given equation.

So, It's impossible to express those variables in single free variable.

Comment: From this you must have $x=y$. But $z$ is defined on points where $x \ne y$, and your parametric equation cannot cover those.

Comment: @player3236 I edited.

Comment: Four comments: (1) Now your equations depend on three variables. (2) You cannot have $(x,y)=(0,\pi)$, for example. (3) The $\mathbb N \cup \{0\}$ restriction means that $x, y$ cannot be less than $-\pi/2$. (4) I'm not the person who downvoted.

Comment: @player3236 Hmmm,,you are right,,I edit again.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. yeah the problem is i want to draw the surface on solidworks and he only accept parametric equation. and it seems impossible as they are independent of each others.

Answer (score 0):

We need two parameters for the parametrization that is for example the trivial

- $x=u$
- $y=v$
- $z=\sin(2\pi u)\sin(2\pi v)$

or also any

- $x= f(u)$
- $y= g(v)$
- $z=\sin(2\pi f(u))\sin(2\pi g(v))$

such that the ranges for $f(u)$ and $g(v)$ agree with the ranges for $x$ and $y$.

For example, using [that result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Compositions_of_trig_and_inverse_trig_functions), the following

- $x= \frac1{2\pi}\arctan u$
- $y= \frac1{2\pi}\arctan v$
- $z=\sin(2\pi x)\sin(2\pi y)=\frac{uv}{\sqrt{(u^2+1)(v^2+1)}}$

holds with the limitation $x,y \in\left(-\frac14,\frac14\right)$.